# Linear Discrete Dynamical Systems

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have been having a hard time with the topic of discrete dynamical systems in my college linear algebra 2 course; I recall sketching phase portraits in a differential equations class, though it was several years ago and many of the intricacies are now lost on me.

Below is a problem from a past homework assignment that provides matrix A for the discrete dynamical system x(k+1)=Ax(k). The first two parts I am able to complete (finding the characteristic equation, determining the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, etc.), however, I'm stumped when asked to sketch the trajectory through a specific point.

[Homework Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v9Xh.png)

I feel like I would be able to do this if I had a better understanding of how to determine trajectory "behavior." If the problem I provided is too long, here's a few straightforward questions I have:

- How do I determine if the origin is a saddle or node?
- How do I know if the origin is stable or unstable?
- Will the trajectories through specific points follow the same behavior as the trajectories of eigenvectors? (This one is the least ambiguous; I am assuming yes).

Anytime I try to search "sketching trajectories for discrete dynamical systems," I wind up more confused than I started. Any help or clarification is greatly appreciated; cheers!

Comment: Would you be able to analyze the system (and answer your questions) if $A$ were diagonal, $A=\pmatrix{a&0\cr0&b\cr}$? Well, the behavior just depends on the eigenvalues.

Comment: I believe so, however, I'm more so confused by the differing information I've seen on the topic of behavior. As you say, it depends on the eigenvalues, and what I have read says: "If both eigenvalues are positive, the critical point is an unstable node." But my professor has instructed that if λ1>1>λ2>0, it gives rise to a saddle origin. Could you perhaps clear up this discrepancy?

Comment: @upas: The quoted statement refers to *continuous-time* dynamical systems, while your professor is talking about *discrete-time* dynamical systems.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion: is it clear to you that the trajectory through a given point consists of a **sequence of points** when we're dealing with discrete-time systems, as opposed to a **curve** for the continous-time systems that you learned about in that differential equations class?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you've read, and it doesn't matter what your professor said; **you** can figure out, all by yourself, what the story is. Just look at what happens in the example I gave. What is $x(n)$, in terms of $x(0)=(r,s)$ and $n$, when $A$ is the matrix I gave? How does the long-term behavior depend on $a$ and $b$?

Comment: In a sense, plotting a trajectory for a discrete-time system is completely trivial, since if you know one point you can just compute the next one through multiplication by the matrix $A$, and then repeat that until you have as many points as you like. Of course, this is not the end of the story, since what you really want is an understanding of *why* the trajectory looks the way it does, and in particular what happens as $n \to \infty$, and that's where the eigenvalues and eigenvectors enter into the picture.